# R: complete states with 0 by date

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I've a data.frame for some months of 2018. When I do an global aggregation by state (DEPARTAMENTO in Spanish) everything is Ok, I get back a df with the 25 states and somve value in sales for each state.

But when I filter a particular state by a day, I get, for example, just 15 states. Total states are 25:

```
unique(ventas$DEPARTAMENTO) #returns 25 states when the data corresponds a long period
 [1] "LIMA"          "AREQUIPA"      "LA LIBERTAD"   "MOQUEGUA"     
 [5] "HUANUCO"       "CUSCO"         "PIURA"         "CALLAO"       
 [9] "CAJAMARCA"     "UCAYALI"       "JUNIN"         "ICA"          
[13] "LAMBAYEQUE"    "AMAZONAS"      "ANCASH"        "AYACUCHO"     
[17] "LORETO"        "SAN MARTIN"    "TACNA"         "MADRE DE DIOS"
[21] "PUNO"          "TUMBES"        "PASCO"         "APURIMAC"     
[25] "HUANCAVELICA"
```

**How do I do complete the rest of the states missing when they don't appear because no sale was recorded from them that particular date?**

*The case applies on 16/08/2018, on the other hand 15/08/2018 has data for every state.

```
#Returns only 16 states of 25

ventas_departamentos <- ventas %>%
                        filter(FECHA_PED == "16/08/2018") %>%
                        group_by(DEPARTAMENTO) %>%
                        summarise(VENTAS= sum(VENTAS))
```

**Sample data:** It only shows data for 14 states on "16/07/2018" however, there are 25 states.

```
    structure(list(FECHA_PED = c("15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", 
"15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", 
"15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", 
"15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", 
"15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", 
"15/08/2018", "15/08/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", 
"16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", 
"16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/08/2018", 
"16/08/2018", "17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", 
"17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", 
"17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", "17/08/2018", "17/08/2018"), DEPARTAMENTO = c("AMAZONAS", 
"ANCASH", "APURIMAC", "AREQUIPA", "AYACUCHO", "CAJAMARCA", "CALLAO", 
"CUSCO", "HUANCAVELICA", "HUANUCO", "ICA", "JUNIN", "LA LIBERTAD", 
"LAMBAYEQUE", "LIMA", "LORETO", "MADRE DE DIOS", "MOQUEGUA", 
"PASCO", "PIURA", "PUNO", "SAN MARTIN", "TACNA", "TUMBES", "UCAYALI", 
"AMAZONAS", "ANCASH", "AREQUIPA", "AYACUCHO", "CALLAO", "CUSCO", 
"ICA", "LAMBAYEQUE", "LIMA", "LORETO", "MOQUEGUA", "PIURA", "SAN MARTIN", 
"TACNA", "AREQUIPA", "CAJAMARCA", "CALLAO", "CUSCO", "HUANUCO", 
"ICA", "JUNIN", "LA LIBERTAD", "LAMBAYEQUE", "LIMA", "MOQUEGUA", 
"PIURA", "UCAYALI"), VENTAS = c(1545, 1212, 2349.18483011377, 
2349.18483011377, 448.655378691318, 250, 998.040346840917, 1235.83321024607, 
878, 760.094289441334, 1262.85505782431, 474.702268205715, 2001.15771843356, 
2245.18603040845, 51062.7935183381, 186.570326518456, 4548, 410.101788287779, 
1548, 1779.77394863005, 78, 2245.18603040845, 9440.63315148726, 
1500.37246329124, 998.040346840917, 241.361194343254, 751.944809713059, 
3422.55258780341, 833.947218393584, 3270.73872294869, 1814.77433185166, 
818.095057353685, 1737.0159616384, 33361.873446708, 710.900787004681, 
1764.20759408142, 1864.98050395575, 857.36085379108, 588.900514206351, 
2117.36171824294, 346.930386805224, 1648.91437144541, 965.971270003731, 
2001.15771843356, 298.239316298776, 514.223203738548, 1611.43834003938, 
940.833636649437, 22909.898424303, 2323.9439806791, 2337.35194677909, 
888.715034174863)), .Names = c("FECHA_PED", "DEPARTAMENTO", "VENTAS"
), row.names = c(NA, -52L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    FECHA_PED = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), DEPARTAMENTO = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), VENTAS = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("FECHA_PED", "DEPARTAMENTO", "VENTAS"
)), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"), vars = "FECHA_PED", drop = TRUE)
```

This is the structure of the df:

```
FECHA_PED   DEPARTAMENTO    VENTAS
16/08/2018  AMAZONAS        241.36
16/08/2018  ANCASH          751.94
16/08/2018  AREQUIPA        3422.55
16/08/2018  AYACUCHO        833.94
16/08/2018  CALLAO          3270.73
16/08/2018  CUSCO           1814.77
16/08/2018  ICA             818.09
16/08/2018  LAMBAYEQUE      1737.01
16/08/2018  LIMA            33361.87
16/08/2018  LORETO          710.90
16/08/2018  MOQUEGUA        1764.20
16/08/2018  PIURA           1864.98
16/08/2018  SAN MARTIN      857.36
16/08/2018  TACNA           588.90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `group_by()`  to the full dataset but use only the dates you want in `summarise()`.

This below should assign the 10 other states a `VENTAS` of `0`:

```r
ventas_departamentos <- ventas %>%
                    group_by(DEPARTAMENTO) %>%
                    summarise(VENTAS = sum(TOTAL_PEDIDO * (FECHA_PED == "16/08/2018"),
                              na.rm = TRUE))
```

To assign them `NA` instead of `0` you might track the missingness then replace:

```
ventas_departamentos <- ventas %>%
                    group_by(DEPARTAMENTO) %>%
                    summarise(VENTAS = sum(TOTAL_PEDIDO * (FECHA_PED == "16/08/2018"),
                                           na.rm = TRUE),
                              n_obs = sum(FECHA_PED == "16/08/2018", na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                    mutate(VENTAS = replace(VENTAS, n_obs == 0, NA)
```

To summarize on a range of dates, simply modify the logical statement part in the two places:

```
days <- 14:16
dates <- paste0(days, "/08/2018")
dates
# [1] "14/08/2018" "15/08/2018" "16/08/2018"

ventas_departamentos <- ventas %>%
                    group_by(DEPARTAMENTO) %>%
                    summarise(VENTAS = sum(TOTAL_PEDIDO * (FECHA_PED %in% dates),
                                           na.rm = TRUE),
                              n_obs = sum(FECHA_PED %in% dates, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                    mutate(VENTAS = replace(VENTAS, n_obs == 0, NA)
```

Comment: ty It works, may you explain how using the date in the `summarise` function also filters the data for that date???

Comment: Also, it works only when intereset in a particular date? or could be used when interested in a range of dates? If so, how? Could you expand on this?

Comment: Sure -- It's effectively zeroing out the values of TOTAL_PEDIDO in observations for which the date is not the preferred date.  Mechanically,  `(FECHA_PED == "16/08/2018")`  gives a vector of 0s and 1s , and this is multiplied with the TOTAL_PEDIDO vector. So the observations for which the logical is 0 turns into a zero. This is then summed -- and zeros don't affect the sum.

Comment: We could change the two expressions that's currently `FECHA_PED == "16/08/2018"` into whatever logical expression (e.g. date ranges, `%in%`), and everything should be the same.

Comment: cannot get my head around the use of %in% to generate complete states, could you edit your answer to make an example for 14,15,16 of august? ty

Answer (score 1):

The solution below should work for a `ventas` data frame that has any number of dates:

Step 1: build a new df with complete states for each dates, but all ventas values being 0.

```
all_states = unique(ventas$DEPARTAMENTO) 
all_dates = unique(ventas$FECHA_PED)
new_ventas = data.frame(FECHA_PED = rep(all_dates, each=length(all_states)),
                         DEPARTAMENTO = rep(all_states, length(all_dates)), 
                         VENTAS = 0)
```

Step 2: create two VENTAS values vectors, one for `new_ventas$VENTAS` and the other for the original `ventas$VENTAS`. Name the vectors with combined dates and states. This should give you a unique name for each value.

```
new_ventas_values = new_ventas$VENTAS
names(new_ventas_values) = paste0(new_ventas$FECHA_PED, '_', new_ventas$DEPARTAMENTO)

ventas_values = ventas$VENTAS
names(ventas_values) = paste0(ventas$FECHA_PED, '_', ventas$DEPARTAMENTO)
```

Step 3: now you can replace 0s in `new_ventas` with values in `ventas` by using the unique names.

```
new_ventas_values[names(ventas_values)] = ventas_values
new_ventas$VENTAS = new_ventas_values

new_ventas
```

Resulting df would be:

```
    FECHA_PED  DEPARTAMENTO     VENTAS
1  15/08/2018      AMAZONAS  1545.0000
2  15/08/2018        ANCASH  1212.0000
3  15/08/2018      APURIMAC  2349.1848
4  15/08/2018      AREQUIPA  2349.1848
5  15/08/2018      AYACUCHO   448.6554
6  15/08/2018     CAJAMARCA   250.0000
7  15/08/2018        CALLAO   998.0403
8  15/08/2018         CUSCO  1235.8332
9  15/08/2018  HUANCAVELICA   878.0000
10 15/08/2018       HUANUCO   760.0943
11 15/08/2018           ICA  1262.8551
12 15/08/2018         JUNIN   474.7023
13 15/08/2018   LA LIBERTAD  2001.1577
14 15/08/2018    LAMBAYEQUE  2245.1860
15 15/08/2018          LIMA 51062.7935
16 15/08/2018        LORETO   186.5703
17 15/08/2018 MADRE DE DIOS  4548.0000
18 15/08/2018      MOQUEGUA   410.1018
19 15/08/2018         PASCO  1548.0000
20 15/08/2018         PIURA  1779.7739
21 15/08/2018          PUNO    78.0000
22 15/08/2018    SAN MARTIN  2245.1860
23 15/08/2018         TACNA  9440.6332
24 15/08/2018        TUMBES  1500.3725
25 15/08/2018       UCAYALI   998.0403
26 16/08/2018      AMAZONAS   241.3612
27 16/08/2018        ANCASH   751.9448
28 16/08/2018      APURIMAC     0.0000
29 16/08/2018      AREQUIPA  3422.5526
30 16/08/2018      AYACUCHO   833.9472
31 16/08/2018     CAJAMARCA     0.0000
32 16/08/2018        CALLAO  3270.7387
33 16/08/2018         CUSCO  1814.7743
34 16/08/2018  HUANCAVELICA     0.0000
35 16/08/2018       HUANUCO     0.0000
36 16/08/2018           ICA   818.0951
37 16/08/2018         JUNIN     0.0000
38 16/08/2018   LA LIBERTAD     0.0000
39 16/08/2018    LAMBAYEQUE  1737.0160
40 16/08/2018          LIMA 33361.8734
41 16/08/2018        LORETO   710.9008
42 16/08/2018 MADRE DE DIOS     0.0000
43 16/08/2018      MOQUEGUA  1764.2076
44 16/08/2018         PASCO     0.0000
45 16/08/2018         PIURA  1864.9805
46 16/08/2018          PUNO     0.0000
47 16/08/2018    SAN MARTIN   857.3609
48 16/08/2018         TACNA   588.9005
49 16/08/2018        TUMBES     0.0000
50 16/08/2018       UCAYALI     0.0000
51 17/08/2018      AMAZONAS     0.0000
52 17/08/2018        ANCASH     0.0000
53 17/08/2018      APURIMAC     0.0000
54 17/08/2018      AREQUIPA  2117.3617
55 17/08/2018      AYACUCHO     0.0000
56 17/08/2018     CAJAMARCA   346.9304
57 17/08/2018        CALLAO  1648.9144
58 17/08/2018         CUSCO   965.9713
59 17/08/2018  HUANCAVELICA     0.0000
60 17/08/2018       HUANUCO  2001.1577
61 17/08/2018           ICA   298.2393
62 17/08/2018         JUNIN   514.2232
63 17/08/2018   LA LIBERTAD  1611.4383
64 17/08/2018    LAMBAYEQUE   940.8336
65 17/08/2018          LIMA 22909.8984
66 17/08/2018        LORETO     0.0000
67 17/08/2018 MADRE DE DIOS     0.0000
68 17/08/2018      MOQUEGUA  2323.9440
69 17/08/2018         PASCO     0.0000
70 17/08/2018         PIURA  2337.3519
71 17/08/2018          PUNO     0.0000
72 17/08/2018    SAN MARTIN     0.0000
73 17/08/2018         TACNA     0.0000
74 17/08/2018        TUMBES     0.0000
75 17/08/2018       UCAYALI   888.7150
```